# Webpack 4: include many JSON files in output using file-loader

Tags: json, webpack, backbone.js

I am using Webpack 4, and am trying to achieve the following:

The `collections/` folder contains *many* JSON files, which I want to include in my output folder in the form `[name].[chunkhash].json` (or a variation of this).

In the JS file, I want to require them dynamically, e.g. 
`` import(`collections/${name}.json`) ``. Furthermore, I would like this require statement to resolve to the URL for the chunk, so I can fetch it using Backbone.

Seems `file-loader` would be the perfect candidate for it, but I'm having a hard time making it work with JSON files.

**webpack.config.js**

```
{
  test: [
    /\.json$/
  ],
 type: 'javascript/auto',
 include: [/generated/],
 loader: 'file-loader'
}
```

**Backbone model**

```
url: function() {
    return import(`collections/${this.get('id')}.json`);
}
```

I'd like the `import` statement here to be replaced with the URL of the JSON file in the output folder. What style of import should be used here?

P.S. I would like to avoid `copy-webpack-plugin` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here is to use `require()` instead of `import()`, which will *synchronously* resolve to the asset's URL:

**Backbone model**

```
url: function() {
  return require(`collections/${this.get('id')}.json`);
}
```